# How to get correct week for 2017-01-01?

Tags: php, date, cakephp, datepicker

I have start and end date-picker option in my code. Any user can choose starting and end week to get the weekly data.

I want to get week number along with year But if I choose 2017-01-01 as a start date and 2017-02-25 as end date it shows week 52 and year 2017 as week start from 2nd January. Is there any way to get the correct week and year?

```
$start     = new DateTime($event->data['requestData']['input_from']); //it takes start date
$end       = new DateTime($event->data['requestData']['input_to']); //it takes end date
$interval   = new DateInterval('P1W');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $dt) {
$newItems[$dt->format('Y.W')] = array('year' => $dt->format('Y'), 'week'=> $dt->format('W'));
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [2017.52] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [week] => 52
        )

    [2017.01] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [week] => 01
        )

    [2017.02] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [week] => 02
        )

    [2017.03] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [week] => 03
        )

    [2017.04] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [week] => 04
        )

    [2017.05] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [week] => 05
        )

    [2017.06] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [week] => 06
        )

    [2017.07] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [week] => 07
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this. Use **"o"** specifier in format to show  **"The ISO-8601 year number"** instead of current year. Changed **$dt->format('Y.W')** to  **$dt->format('o.W')** as follow

```
  foreach ($period as $dt) {
        $newItems[$dt->format('o.W')] = array('year' => $dt->format('o'), 'week'=> $dt->format('W'));
        }
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [2016.52] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2016
            [week] => 52
        )

    [2017.01] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [week] => 01
        )

    [2017.02] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [week] => 02
        )

    [2017.03] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [week] => 03
        )

    [2017.04] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [week] => 04
        )

    [2017.05] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [week] => 05
        )

    [2017.06] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [week] => 06
        )

    [2017.07] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2017
            [week] => 07
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should read the definition of the [first week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week).
January 1st is not by definition in week 1. Week numbering starts on a Monday, so if January 1st is on a Sunday, like it was the case in 2017, it is technically in week 52 of the previous year (Even though it is in its own year).

Your code is thus technically giving you the correct result: January 1st 2017 is in the year 2017, but it is also in week 52 (of 2016).

Comment: I know that code is technically giving me the correct result but isn't there any way to achieve the requirement??